# Provide default value for querystring param with pipes on NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to implement [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#providing-defaults) example. It looks so simple to implement but I have some troubles.

```
@Get('test')
async test(
  @Query('size', new DefaultValuePipe(10), ParseIntPipe) size: number,
  @Query('page', new DefaultValuePipe(1), ParseIntPipe) page: number,
) {
   // Do some stuff
}
```

- The first request I've made is `http://localhost/api/test`

  - The requests I sent without params are replied with `400 Bad Request` and the message is `Validation failed (numeric string is expected)`.
- The second request I've made is `http://localhost/api/test?size=&page=`

  - The requests I sent with empty params are passed as `0`, not with the value that I want to be provided by default.

In both requests, the default values are expected to pass, right? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide a repro?